# Cannot use object of type Closure as array

Tags: php, drupal

fatal error " Cannot use object of type Closure as array", how to fix this problem. code i am using is as below

```
function message_broker_example_message_broker_consumers($self_name) {
  $consumers = array();

  // An example consumer implemented using a closure.
  $consumers['helloWorldToEveryone'] = array(
    'queue' => 'helloWorldForAll',
    'callback' => function($message, \Closure $ack) {
      $message = json_decode($message->body);

      if ($message->name == 'crash') {
        throw new InvalidMessageException('Invalid name detected!');
      }

      if (function_exists('drush_print')) {
        drush_print('Hello world, ' . $message->name);
      }
      else {
        drupal_set_message(t('Hello world, @name.', array('@name' => $message->name)));
      }

      $ack();
    }, 'invalidMessageHandler' => function($message) {
      if (function_exists('drush_print')) {
        drush_print('Invalid message handler was executed.');
      }
      else {
        drupal_set_message(t('Invalid message handler was executed.'), 'warning');
      }
    });
```

the code is snippet from drupal message_broker module

Comment: Is the error being thrown at a specific line in your snippet?

Comment: This error means that somewhere there is an instance of the class `Closure` that is being accessed like an array using square brackets. I'm assuming it is elsewhere, because no where in this code is this happening. For an example and to show the problem [you can look here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DvHuJq). This often times happens with `StdClass` (instead of closure) and using json_decode without the second parameter to force an array. To fix it, you need to go to the file/line and replace `$instance["property"]` with object accessor like `$instance->property`. Same applies for methods.

Comment: It helps to take note of the full text of the error message. It will indicate the exact point in the code that the problem occurs at. Then, you can check that line, often the problem is obvious when you've got an error message and location to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.call-user-func-array.php)

```
function message_broker_example_message_broker_consumers($self_name) {
$consumers = array();

// An example consumer implemented using a closure.
$consumers['helloWorldToEveryone'] = array(
'queue' => 'helloWorldForAll',
'callback' => call_user_func_array(function($message, \Closure $ack) {
  $message = json_decode($message->body);

  if ($message->name == 'crash') {
    throw new InvalidMessageException('Invalid name detected!');
  }

  if (function_exists('drush_print')) {
    drush_print('Hello world, ' . $message->name);
  }
  else {
    drupal_set_message(t('Hello world, @name.', array('@name' => $message->name)));
  }

  $ack();
}, [$message, $ack]),
'invalidMessageHandler' => call_user_func_array(function($message) {
  if (function_exists('drush_print')) {
    drush_print('Invalid message handler was executed.');
  }
  else {
    drupal_set_message(t('Invalid message handler was executed.'), 'warning');
  }
}, [$message]));
```