# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Closure as array

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this snippet of code that seems to break my site when I update a particular plugin. The plugin I updated appears to being closures some where because I get the error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Closure as array.

The error traces back to this code:

```
if (!empty($wp_filter['admin_menu'])) {
    foreach($wp_filter['admin_menu'] as $cb) {
        foreach ($cb as $k => $v) {
            if (
                isset($v['function'])
                && is_a($v['function'][0],'Ma_Settings_PN')
                && isset($v['function'][1])
                && 'add_menu_item_push_notifications' == $v['function'][1]
            ) {
                remove_action('admin_menu',$k);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From what I gather this code is used to remove an action from a particular class somewhere else. What is the best way to get rid of this Fatal error?

Comment: Do you have the full text of the error message? Look [cannot-use-object-of-type-closure-as-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772821/cannot-use-object-of-type-closure-as-array)

Comment: Why do you use `$v['function']` what seems the place where the closure is, as array? Because if `$v['function']` is the closure,that `$v['function'][0]` will throw an fatal error.

Comment: The full error message is: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Closure as array in /vagrant/document_root/wp-content/plugins/wp-MobileAppPluginMmpExtension/classes/settings/class-ma-mmp-settings-pn.php on line 100 and line 100 is && is_a($v['function'][0],'Ma_Settings_PN')

Comment: when cycling through all the functions within the admin_menu hook some are strings, some are functions, some are objects....